# Qt Installer Framework Uninstaller

Tags: qt, uninstallation, qt-installer, qtif

Is there any script or example of Qt installer framework for "Un-installer"? I want to remove some folders using the maintenance tool.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/ifw-use-cases-remove.html) for Qt installer framework, the "uninstall" part is simply built in. Running the maintenance tool after install will provide the end user with the option of removing components or the entire package.

So for each component you have previously specified in your configuration, it will automatically show up as something that you can un-install.

Here is the screenshot from the documentation for reference:

[image]

Comment: This is not the required answer. The solution was asked in script.